# Ruby array sort without changing position of nils

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting

I am working with an array of arrays. I need to sort the rows, and the sort criteria is the value of each column (starting with the 2nd column) successively from left to right. Nil values must be pushed to the bottom. Once pushed to the bottom, I need to leave nil columns as they are without successive searches changing their position relative to each other. Starting with this array:

```
sort_array = 
[[297, 100, 101, 235, 253, nil, nil, nil],
 [286, 116, 116, 213, nil, nil, nil, nil],
 [256, 105, 111, 212, 216, 264, nil, nil],
 [276, 108, 111, 204, 207, 257, 259, 367],
 [274,  66,  66, 120, 121, nil, 150, nil],
 [298, 114, 117, 270, 270, nil, nil, nil],
 [296, 127, 130, 259, 264, 324, 332, nil],
 [283, 102, 106, 193, 199, 247, 248, 343]]
```

I iterate across the array with these lines of code:

```
(1..sort_array[0].size - 1).each do |i|
  sort_array.sort_by! { |e| [e[i] ? 0 : 1, e[i]] }
end
```

The idea is to ignore the first column, but sort the second through nth column in ascending order pushing nil values to the bottom. This gives the following result:

```
  => [[283, 102, 106, 193, 199, 247, 248, 343],
     [276, 108, 111, 204, 207, 257, 259, 367],
     [256, 105, 111, 212, 216, 264, nil, nil],
     [297, 100, 101, 235, 253, nil, nil, nil],
     [296, 127, 130, 259, 264, 324, 332, nil],
     [274,  66,  66, 120, 121, nil, 150, nil],
     [298, 114, 117, 270, 270, nil, nil, nil],
     [286, 116, 116, 213, nil, nil, nil, nil]]
```

This is close to what I need, but not quite right. The problem is that the nil values once pushed to the bottom don't stay put. For example, after sorting the column whose first value is 247, the array would have looked like this:

```
=> [[283, ... 247, ...]
    [276, ... 257, ...]
    [256, ... 264, ...]
    [296, ... 324, ...]
    [297, ... nil, ...]
    [274, ... nil, ...]
    [298, ... nil, ...]
    [286, ... nil, ...]
```

But further sorting on columns to the right results in the nil values being reordered, which messes up the sort. Nil values need to stay put unless a cell to the right is non-nil, in which case it should be sorted as usual.

The table should look like this when the sort is finished:

```
  => [[283, 102, 106, 193, 199, 247, 248, 343],
     [276, 108, 111, 204, 207, 257, 259, 367],
     [274,  66,  66, 120, 121, nil, 150, nil],
     [296, 127, 130, 259, 264, 324, 332, nil],
     [256, 105, 111, 212, 216, 264, nil, nil],
     [297, 100, 101, 235, 253, nil, nil, nil],
     [298, 114, 117, 270, 270, nil, nil, nil],
     [286, 116, 116, 213, nil, nil, nil, nil]]
```

Could someone please help me write a method that will achieve this result?

It may be helpful to see the real-life example of what I am trying to achieve. Here is a link to a spreadsheet:

https://github.com/SplitTime/OpenSplitTime/blob/master/hardrock2015test.xlsx

Each row is a runner effort. Runners are ranked by final finish time of course. But those who do not finish are ranked by how far they made it and what time they made it to their last waypoint.

Though the linked spreadsheet does not show it, the sort also needs to deal with nil values with time data to the right, representing times that didn't get recorded for whatever reason.

Comment: Not clear what you mean. Elements do not seem to be changed their colums. What do you mean to sort **each column** from the left to right? You can only sort (two or more) **columns** from the left to right.

Comment: Why is the row starting 274,666,666 not further down (since the 2nd to last element is nil) ?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The elements always stay in their columns. The sort affects the rows as a whole. But the sort criteria is applied first to the 2nd column, then to the 3rd, and so on to the nth column. I will edit to clarify.

Comment: The 3-dot range notation is meant for exactly your situation where you would otherwise use `- 1`.  You could instead use `(1...sort_array[0].size).each...`  BTW, why are you starting at 1 and not 0?

Comment: @FrederickCheung, the row starting 274,666,666 would have been at the top of the table after the sort on the 7th column. After the sort on the final column it would be pushed down because its 8th element is nil.

Comment: If the elements stay in their columns and the sort affects the rows as a whole, then you are sorting the rows, not the columns. Not clear what you mean.

Comment: @moveson but why is it not pushed down (and left at the bottom) because of the nil in column 6?

Comment: @sawa: The question is how can I write a method that results in the table shown? My method works except that it changes position of the nil values in subsequent column sorts. For an example of how this should work, if you were to enter the same data into MS Excel (leaving blank cells where I am using nil) and sort the 2nd column, then the 3rd, and on to the last, and you will get the proper result.

Comment: @FrederickCheung: It is pushed down when column 6 is sorted. (See my interim illustration with the dots.) But then column 7 is sorted, and then column 8. I care about where it ends up after the sort on column 8.

Comment: @sawa: Yes, I am sorting the rows, but sorting ON each column, one at a time, from left to right. The reason for the multiple sorts is to achieve the result shown in the final table, because I care about the order of those nil values.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: Yes, a typo, thanks for catching that. I've fixed it.

Comment: @KeithBennett: I did not know that about the three-dot range. Thanks for the tip. I'm starting at 1 because my 0 column is made up of keys, not values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* that you want to sort the rows by its 2nd to last elements in reverse order (with `nil` being treated as `Infinity`):

```
arrays = [[297, 100, 101, 235, 253, nil, nil, nil],
          [286, 116, 116, 213, nil, nil, nil, nil],
          [256, 105, 111, 212, 216, 264, nil, nil],
          [276, 108, 111, 204, 207, 257, 259, 367],
          [274,  66,  66, 120, 121, nil, 150, nil],
          [298, 114, 117, 270, 270, nil, nil, nil],
          [296, 127, 130, 259, 264, 324, 332, nil],
          [283, 102, 106, 193, 199, 247, 248, 343]]

arrays.sort_by { |a| a[1..-1].reverse.map { |e| e || Float::INFINITY } }
#=> [[283, 102, 106, 193, 199, 247, 248, 343],
#    [276, 108, 111, 204, 207, 257, 259, 367],
#    [274,  66,  66, 120, 121, nil, 150, nil],
#    [296, 127, 130, 259, 264, 324, 332, nil],
#    [256, 105, 111, 212, 216, 264, nil, nil],
#    [297, 100, 101, 235, 253, nil, nil, nil],
#    [298, 114, 117, 270, 270, nil, nil, nil],
#    [286, 116, 116, 213, nil, nil, nil, nil]]
```

At least, this produces the expected result.

Since the first row consists of keys, you could take advantage of Ruby's [array decomposition](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/doc/syntax/methods_rdoc.html#label-Array+Decomposition) abilities and use `|_, *vs| vs.reverse...` instead of `|a| a[1..-1].reverse...`. Here, `_` refers to the (unused) key and `*vs` collects the remaining elements.

Comment: This would produce the desired result in this case but I am looking for an algorithm that produces the desired result in every case.

Comment: @moveson could you give a counter-example?

Comment: I stand corrected. Your code works perfectly and instantly. Thank you so much! I still don't understand quite what it does. Could you explain?

Comment: @moveson `arrays.map { |a| a[1..-1].reverse.map { |e| e || Float::INFINITY } }` returns the intermediate array the sorting is based upon.

Comment: I see now! I did not realize an array sort could evaluate elements that are themselves arrays. This is wonderful. Again, thank you!